# Vim LSP: change keybindings only if there is a LS attached to buffer

Tags: key-bindings, lsp

I do maintain there mappings in mv $vimrc:

```
augroup LSP | au!
autocmd FileType go,json,yaml nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <c-]> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>
autocmd FileType go,json,yaml nnoremap <silent> <buffer> gd    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
autocmd FileType go,json,yaml nnoremap <silent> <buffer> K     <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
```

(abbreviated)

However maintaining this becomes tedious: With every language server I add to my system I have to add it on every line next to the autocmd

What I really want is to add these mappings to buffers which have a LS attached. Any way to automatize this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to refactor it, introducing a dedicated function that does all the mappings:

```
func! s:lsp_mappings()
    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <c-]> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> gd    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> K     <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
endfunc


augroup LSP | au!
    autocmd FileType go,json,yaml call s:lsp_mappings()
augroup END
```

And to answer your question -- I don't know for sure, but if your LSP implementation (looks like it is builtin neovim lsp?) has some ways to query if lsp is attached to a buffer, then ("pseudocode"):

```
func! s:lsp_mappings()
    if luaeval('vim.tbl_isempty(vim.lsp.buf_get_clients())') 
        return
    endif

    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <c-]> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> gd    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> K     <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
endfunc


augroup LSP | au!
    autocmd FileType * call s:lsp_mappings()
augroup END
```

Comment: "find a way to query if lsp is attached for a buffer" --> `luaeval('vim.tbl_isempty(vim.lsp.buf_get_clients())')`

Comment: Updated as suggested by @Matt, (didn't test as I don't have neovim with lsp setup at the moment)